# Ubuntu 14.04 mounts external USB drive on boot with option "noauto" in fstab entry

Tags: boot, usb, mount, fstab

I have an external USB drive and a USB thumbdrive connected to my computer. Both have an entry in `/etc/fstab` with the option `noauto` (will post the whole `fstab` entries at the end). While my thumbdrive doesn't get mounted at boot time (the behaviour I expect and want), my USB drive does.

Does anyone have any idea what could cause this (and possibly a fix for this)?

`/etc/fstab` entries:

```
UUID=3C33-6F2E /mnt/3C33-6F2E auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto,x-gvfs-show 0 0
UUID=0AD8D11ED8D10939 /mnt/0AD8D11ED8D10939 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

Comment: Is **autofs** enabled on your system? It may be acting on your drive.

Comment: @0xSheepdog **autofs** doesn't seem to be installed. `sudo service autofs status` returns `autofs: unrecognized service`

Comment: Is the USB hard drive partition flagged as bootable? Perhaps the BIOS/EFI see it during initialization and probe it for a valid boot device? I'm not certain, but thinking/guessing through various options (thus the comments and no answer).

Comment: The drive isn't flagged at all (atleast gparted doesn't show any flags).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nautilus can automount USB media using `udisks`.

- Check

  ```
  gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount
  ```

  If `true`, disable it.

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount false
  ```

BTW, There is a graphic tool called `dconf-editor` that let you search through dconf settings. It may help find out what want is such similar case.

1. Install it

   ```
   sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
   ```
2. Launch it → <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>
3. Enter: `automount` then <kbd>Enter</kbd>

It is an exact search tool. If you can't find anything try to search for other possible option: `auto_mount`, `auto-mount` ...

Comment: @DennisHein, Nice to hear that. I have updated it so you it help you solve similar cases in the future.